# "Divert" vs "Deviate"

Tags: differences

I am not able to understand the difference between "divert" and "deviate".

https://www.gingersoftware.com/english-online/spelling-book/confusing-words/divert-deviate

This website mentioned above tries to explain but still, the 2 meanings look the same. Even if I Google the answer, this is what WikiDiff snippet says:

"is that deviate is to go off course from; to change course; to change plans while divert is to turn aside from a course."

Hep me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divert is a transitive verb (needs an object) (you divert something)

> divert
>
> verb [transitive]
>
> (CHANGE DIRECTION) ​
>
> C2 to cause something or someone to change direction:
>
> *Traffic will be diverted through the side streets while the main road
>   is resurfaced.
>
>   Our flight had to be diverted to Newark because of the
>   storm.*

Deviate is an intransitive verb (does not have an object) (something deviates).

> deviate
>
> verb
>
> [intransitive]
>
> (DIRECTION)
>
> to go in a different direction:
>
> The path follows the river closely, occasionally deviating around a
>   clump of trees.

Cambridge Dictionary links:

[Divert](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/divert)
[Deviate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deviate)
[Transitive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/transitive)
[Intransitive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/intransitive)

Answer (score -1):

Let's consider a scenario where Dev is in his last year at University. Let's also imagine that he meets Charlotte on a trip to Europe, they fall in love, and he decides not to finish his degree.

> Charlotte diverted / *deviated Dev from his degree.
>
> Dev deviated / ?diverted from his life plans when he met Charlotte.

or perhaps

> Dev deviated / diverted *himself* from his life plans when he met Charlotte.

And a second scenario where Dev is a pilot.

> The air traffic controllers diverted / *deviated Dev to a less crowded airport.
>
> Dev inadvertently deviated / *diverted from his flight path.

In both scenarios, the Dev has some force divert him from a planned path. (That force is usually external (Charlotte, the air traffic controllers) but may also be internal.)  And in both scenarios, Dev is the actor who is deviating from that path.

Comment: rajah9, you have very effectively _not_ answered the question.

Comment: Yep, that's my aim: To not effectively answer the question. You sussed me out.